# how to store string value to array string and can call that array in another class to Print as string in single line

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to do some work on Mobile apps.
I have parser in `class: A`

```
for (int i = 0; i < jArray3.length(); i++) {
    news_id = Integer.parseInt((json_data.getString("news_id")));
    news_title = json_data.getString("news_title");
}
```

I have to parse and get value of id and title. Now I want to store this title in array and call another class. In that class we have to convert that array into `String` so that i can print that title value in single line.

How can I implement this can u post some code for me?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your question, I assume the following snippet only you are looking for.

```
String[] parsedData = new String[2];
for (int i = 0; i < jArray3.length(); i++) {
    news_id = Integer.parseInt((json_data.getString("news_id")));
news_title = json_data.getString("news_title");
}

parsedData[0] = news_id;
parsedData[1] = news_title;

DifferentCls diffCls = new DifferentCls(data);
System.out.println(diffCls.toString());
```

DifferentCls.java

```
private String[] data = null;

public DifferentCls(String[] data) {
 this.data = data;
}

public String toString() {
 return data[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 news_title = json_data.getString("news_title");

 Add line after the above line to add parse value  int0 string array
```

String[] newRow = new String[] {news_id ,news_title};

**//Convert array to String**

```
  String asString = Arrays.toString(newRow )
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** I am assuming that you have **more than one title to be stored.**

I am using `ArrayList<String>` which is **more flexible than** `Array`.

Creating an ArrayList and Storing all the title values:

```
ArrayList<String> titleArr = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < jArray3.length(); i++) {
    news_id = Integer.parseInt((json_data.getString("news_id")));
    news_title = json_data.getString("news_title");

    titleArr.add(news_title);
}
```

**2.** Now **sending it to** `another class`, where you need to Show all the titles in Single Line.

```
new AnotherClass().alistToString(titleArr);  


// This line should be after the for-loop
// alistToString() is a method in another class
```

**3.** Another class structure.

```
 public class AnotherClass{

      //.................. Your code...........


       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       String titleStr = new String();

    public void alistToString(ArrayList<String> arr){

    for (String s : arr){

     sb.append(s+"\n");   // Appending each value to StrinBuilder with a space.

          }

    titleStr = sb.toString();  // Now here you have the TITLE STRING....ENJOY !!

      }

    //.................. Your code.............

   }
```